# What is the equivalent of PACK in OO context?

Tags: abap

Here's one for you.

I have a number delivered in a text file as a packed number of length 13 with 2 decimal places.

```
0000000627909
```

so in reality it represents the following number `6279.09`.

Now in the old world there was this beautiful ABAP sentence...

```
PACK packed_number TO number_with_decimal_type
```

...unfortunately this is not allowed in OO context and marked as [obsolete](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abappack.htm) with a comment that a normal assignment does the same. Well, it does not... at least not where there are decimal places to be concerned.

Here is an example:

```
REPORT zzpj_unpack_test.
DATA:
  BEGIN OF gs_structured,
    loan_entitlement TYPE c LENGTH 13,
  END OF gs_structured.
DATA: gv_packed TYPE p LENGTH 13 DECIMALS 2.

INITIALIZATION.
  gs_structured = VALUE #(
      loan_entitlement = '0000000627909'
    ).
  DATA(gs_dc) = CORRESPONDING /ibs/sbsc_change_main( gs_structured ).
  PACK gs_structured-loan_entitlement TO gv_packed. "works beautifilly!
  gv_packed = gs_structured-loan_entitlement. "does not care about decimal places

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA ls_structured LIKE gs_structured.
    DATA lv_packed TYPE p LENGTH 13 DECIMALS 2.

    ls_structured = VALUE #(
      loan_entitlement = '0000000627909'
    ).
    "PACK gs_structured-loan_entitlement TO gv_packed. "does not work in OO context
    lv_packed = ls_structured-loan_entitlement. "does not care about decimal places
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

A simple assignment makes `627909.00` out of what should be `6279.09`.

So my question is: what is the **real** equivalent of `PACK` sentence in OO context?

Comment: As far as I know, the only use case for `PACK` is for storing currency amounts in the "old SAP world". Instead, you may use the method `CONVERT_DECFLOAT_TO_CURR` of `CL_ABAP_DECFLOAT`.

Comment: Hi Sandra, thanks for the comment but it does not work for me. The input is de facto a character chain of length 13 and not of type DECFLOAT34. I think I will just put `PACK` sentence in my own function module. Then I would be able at least to call it from a method.

Comment: The fact that the number is stored in a C type is not an issue if you convert it to a 16 or 34 decfloat type first. But I guess that your use case is not about currency so I post an answer for general solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may make ABAP believe that your packed number has 0 decimals although it hasn't, via [`ASSIGN gv_packed TO <p> DECIMALS 0.`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapassign_casting.htm):

```
CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS simulate_pack.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD simulate_pack.                             "<===  simulate PACK
    DATA: gv_packed TYPE p LENGTH 13 DECIMALS 2.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <dec> TYPE p.
    ASSIGN gv_packed TO <dec> CASTING DECIMALS 0.   "<===  <dec> points to GV_PACKED memory
    <dec> = '0000000627909'.                        "<===  assigns the value to GV_PACKED !

    " Check Actual values = Expected values
    ASSERT <dec> = 627909.
    ASSERT gv_packed = '6279.09'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_app=>simulate_pack( ).

  DATA: gv_packed TYPE p LENGTH 13 DECIMALS 2.
  PACK '0000000627909' TO gv_packed.                "<===  use PACK
  " Check Actual value = Expected value
  ASSERT gv_packed = '6279.09'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is very clever, although I will post my own solution as well.

I just created a simple function module that does the work as the `PACK` sentence is allowed in its context. Then I use such a function module in methods of my classes, which is (still :) ) possible.

```
FUNCTION Z_PACK_NUMBER.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(IV_PACKED_NUMBER) TYPE  C
*"  EXPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(EV_VALUE) TYPE  P
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

  PACK iv_packed_number TO ev_value.

ENDFUNCTION.
```